# How to auto-reload code loaded by load magic in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

Jupyter Notebook has a `%load` magic that can load code into a cell of a notebook.

```py
%load start.py
```

This line loads the content of `start.py` into the current cell. The magic is automatically commented out after execution.

```py
# %load start.py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Jupyter Notebook also has a `%autoreload` extension that can reload modules before executing code.

```py
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
from utils import load_data
```

If there is a change in the `load_data` function, this extension can detect and auto-reload the new function before execution.

Is there a way to combine the functionality of these two? In other words, if the content of `start.py` change, how can I automatically detect the change and reload it into the cell before running code?

For example, if the content of `start.py` is now

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I would like the cell to be reloaded to become:

```py
# %load start.py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to mix things beyond the point they were intended.

If you want a hack, as you mention you could import a function from within `start.py`, then `%autoreload` will give you the functionality you want. You could then mix with this if you wanted to see the contents of the `.py` file:

```
with open("start.py") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

You could then easily copy and paste into a cell if needed.